# I am getting error name 'guild' is not defined

Tags: discord, discord.py

.Jsk py

```py
a = guild.get_member(762918430315249684)
await a.edit(nick="Circuit",reason="Because you're Circuit")
```

Comment: please share your entire code

Comment: if you are trying to use jishaku, it's `_guild`

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the full traceback of any errors

Comment: @3nws it is not working

Comment: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jishaku/repl/compilation.py", line 154, in traverse
    async for send, result in AsyncSender(func_g(*self.args)):  # type: ignore
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jishaku/functools.py", line 125, in _internal
    value = await base.asend(self.send_value)
  File "<repl>", line 1, in _repl_coroutine
    a = guild.get_member(762918430315249684)
NameError: name 'guild' is not defined

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```py
a = ctx.guild.get_member(762918430315249684)
await a.edit(nick="Circuit",reason="Because you're Circuit")
```

This would take the Guild to which the message was sent.